# docker compose run --rm web bin/setupでyarn installが実行されるようにしたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

dockerでrailsの開発環境を構築しており、
dockefileのwebコンテナでyarnが動作するようにしたいです。そして、
`docker compose run --rm web bin/setup`でyarn installが実行されるようにしたいです。
現在はこのようにエラーとなっています。

```
The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied
Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install

== Command ["bin/yarn"] failed ==
```

- コンテナ内でyanrが見つからないです

```
root@d5ddf41fc3c6:/rails-docker-mysql# yarn --version
bash: yarn: command not found
```

- docker-compose upでサーバーは起動できます

Dockerfile

```
# Node.js&yarn
FROM node:16-buster-slim
COPY --from=node /opt/yarn-* /opt/yarn
COPY --from=node /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
RUN ln -fs /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js /usr/local/bin/npm \
  && ln -fs /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js /usr/local/bin/npx \
  && ln -fs /opt/yarn/bin/yarn /usr/local/bin/yarn \
  && ln -fs /opt/yarn/bin/yarnpkg /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg

# Rails
FROM ruby:2.7.7
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    default-mysql-client



WORKDIR /rails-docker-mysql
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock /rails-docker-mysql/
RUN bundle install
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

volumes:
  data:

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'

    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ".:/rails-docker-mysql"
    environment:
      - "DATABASE_PASSWORD=password"
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      - "data:/var/lib/mysql"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

dockerfileやdocker-compose.ymlの記述が間違っている場合修正お願いします

Comment: Dockerfile 内でシンボリックリンクを作成しているようですが、コンテナ内に直接入って `/usr/local/bin/yarn` を実行するとどうなりますか？ `/usr/local/bin` への PATH が通っていない、もしくは何らかの原因でシンボリックリンクに失敗している等が考えられます。

Comment: `rails-docker-mysql# /usr/local/bin/yarn
bash: /usr/local/bin/yarn: No such file or directory` となりました

Comment: 同じくコンテナ内で `/opt/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION/bin/yarn` のようなファイルはありませんか？(恐らくは `/opt/yarn-v1.22.19/bin/yarn`)

Answer (score 1):

直接試す環境が無いので憶測を含みます。

ベースの Docker イメージの中身を見ると、以下の通り `/opt/yarn-v${YARN_VERSION}/bin/yarn` に対して `/usr/local/bin/yarn` で参照できるようシンボリックリンクを作成しており、ユーザーが何もしなくても yarn コマンドが標準で使える状態だと思われます。

[docker-node/16/buster-slim/Dockerfile](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/754ca131a9c4f7e4ac8c255cbb3e35a446f5b70c/16/buster-slim/Dockerfile#L73)

> ```bash
> && tar -xzf yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz -C /opt/ \
>   && ln -s /opt/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION/bin/yarn /usr/local/bin/yarn \
> ```

しかし、質問中の Dockerfile では `/opt/yarn/bin/yarn` という (恐らく存在しない) ファイルに対してシンボリックリンクを作成し直しているので、無効なファイルとなり、結果的に yarn コマンドの実行に失敗している気がします。

> ```
> RUN ln -fs /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js /usr/local/bin/npm \
>   && ln -fs /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js /usr/local/bin/npx \
>   && ln -fs /opt/yarn/bin/yarn /usr/local/bin/yarn \
>   && ln -fs /opt/yarn/bin/yarnpkg /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg
> ```

`/opt/yarn/bin/` 以下へのシンボリックリンクを除外した状態でコンテナの起動と yarn コマンドが実行できるかを試してみてください。

Comment: ```COPY --from=node /opt/yarn-* /opt/yarn
COPY --from=node /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
RUN ln -fs /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js /usr/local/bin/npm \
  && ln -fs /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js /usr/local/bin/npx/
RUN yarn install```   変更して、再度buildしましたが`docker compose run --rm web bin/setup`を実行しても同じ結果となりました